# How to get highest values from two columns in a table (SQL)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have a table that has n rows like this:

```
.ID.|.Cycle.|.Week.|..Date...|.Type. 

.1..|...1...|..1...|.12-12-12|.a.

.2..|...1...|..2...|.12-12-12|.a. 

.3..|...1...|..3...|.12-12-12|.a.

.4..|...1...|..4...|.12-12-12|.a.

.5..|...2...|..1...|.12-12-12|.a.

.6..|...2...|..2...|.12-12-12|.a.

.7..|...2...|..2...|.12-12-12|.some_value.
```

So here I'd want to get back cycle 2, week 2 of type "some_value" because cycle 2 is the largest cycle number in the table, and week 2 is the largest week number in cycle 2.

Right now I use query

```
SELECT cycle=MAX(cycle),week=MAX(week)
FROM table 
WHERE TYPE=some_value
```

But I have a feeling this isn't right because I don't seem to get correct values. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT week,
       cycle
FROM   table
WHERE  cycle = (SELECT Max(cycle)
                FROM   table
                WHERE  TYPE = some_value)
       AND TYPE = some_value
ORDER  BY week DESC 
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
select cycle, week
from table
where type = somevalue
order by cycle desc
limit 1;
```

Your query is returning the maximum of the cycle and of the week independently.

Comment: I think so, will your query return the highest value for week too?

Comment: This query will return the highest value of cycle along with the week when it occurred.